# Why is my query taking so long? SQL server 2016 SP2 (13.0.5026.0)

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJtipVIQp

I have implemented this query in some scripting used for energy monitoring (kWh usage). Initially when it was deployed the query returned results within a few 100ms.

At the moment this performance has degraded to take a massive 8-9 seconds per query. i am having trouble figuring out why this is. If someone could help me / point out what the issue seems to be it would be greatly appreciated.

**ADDED:**

`exec sp_linkedservers;` returns:

| SRV_NAME | SRV_PROVIDERNAME | SRV_PRODUCT | SRV_DATASOURCE | SRV_PROVIDERSTRING | SRV_LOCATION | SRV_CAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| INSQL | INSQL |  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| INSQLD | INSQL |  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| MS-SQL-A2502 | SQLNCLI | SQL Server | MS-SQL-A2502 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

running

```sql
select *
from sys.synonyms
where name = 'history'
  and schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')
  and base_object_name like 'runtime.%''
```

returns no result

**UPDATE (what kind of object is runtime.dbo.hsitory):**

Documentation gives me :

```
Because normal Microsoft SQL Server functionality cannot handle the storage and retrieval of huge 
quantities of rapidly changing data, plant data storage and retrieval are made possible by the AVEVA 
Historian storage subsystem, the history tables, and the retrieval system.
Some of the history tables are implemented as normal SQL Server tables, and the information contained 
in them is stored in the Runtime database file (Run110Dat.mdf). Others are implemented as a special 
type of table called a **remote table**, or **extension table**. Extension tables do not actually exist in the 
database, but rather expose data that is stored in special history files (history blocks) on disk using OLE 
DB technology
```

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that `runtime.dbo.history` is a synonym to a linked server, as your query uses a remote query.

Comment: @ThomA i have limited knowledge of database so i had to look up how to verify if it is a synonym. running this query: SELECT *
FROM sys.synonyms
WHERE name = 'history'
AND schema_id = SCHEMA_ID('dbo')
AND base_object_name LIKE 'runtime.%';        this returns no result. so to my understanding this history table is not a synonym.

Comment: So what is that object? There's a remote query in there, so you are clearly querying a remote database.

Comment: Does this return anything? `SELECT * FROM Runtime.sys.synonyms AS s WHERE s.name = 'history'`?

Comment: @ThomA i updated the post with some context from the documentation. is this helpful ?

Comment: I didn't post that comment. From the "code" you've added the question, I'm guessing the data is the latter (your image doesn't help us).

Comment: So from the documentation you have posted it seems you are using a third party tool (AVEVA Historian), which is saving data as files and exposing the data as synonyms. If you're having issues with that 3rd party Software your best bet is to speak to AVEVA to find out why, and if there is anything they can do to change it. It is unlikely anyone here (unless they happen to work for AVEVA) is going to be able to help on this one